# Dealing with floor function in binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to estimate $\binom{n}{\left \lfloor{\alpha n}\right \rfloor }$ asymptotically using Stirling's formula. However, I'm a little lost with what to do about the floor function here.

In the case without the floor function, there is a greater ease to combine the $\alpha$ and $n$ terms, such as
$$\binom{n}{\alpha n}=\frac{n!}{\alpha n!(n-\alpha n)!} \sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}{\sqrt{2\pi \alpha n}\left(\frac{\alpha n}{e}\right)^{\alpha n} \sqrt{2\pi (n-\alpha n)}\left(\frac{(n-\alpha n)}{e}\right)^{(n-\alpha n)}}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi\alpha (n- \alpha n)}
\alpha^{\alpha n}\left(\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\right)^{(\alpha - 1)} 
\left(\frac{(n-\alpha n)}{e}\right)^{(n-\alpha n)}}$$
I'm not sure if there's a further simplification of this (if there is, please left me know!) but I'm also not sure how this would work with the floor function.

I tried splitting into cases, so if $\frac{1}{\alpha}<n$, then $\left \lfloor{\alpha n}\right \rfloor=0 \implies \binom{n}{\left \lfloor{\alpha n}\right \rfloor}=n!$ and when $\frac{1}{\alpha}=n$, then $\left \lfloor{\alpha n}\right \rfloor=1 \implies \binom{n}{\left \lfloor{\alpha n}\right \rfloor}=n!$. However, the case when $\frac{1}{\alpha}>n$ leaves $\left \lfloor{\alpha n}\right \rfloor$ the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asymptotic expansion you have written
without the floor function
implicitly uses the floor function
or you couldn't have approximated
$(\alpha n)!$.

What you have done is a good start.
The next thing to do
is replace all occurrences
of
$n-\alpha n$
by
$n(1-\alpha)$
so you can group more terms
with $n$ together.

I'll let you do that.
If you still have problems,
comment and
I'll proceed further.

Comment: But where would the floor go in expressions such as $\left(\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right)^{\alpha-1}$? would they be around the entire expression $n(\alpha-1)$?

Comment: I would say to forget about the floor function. The values are off by less than one, so the Stirling approximations will be good enough.

Comment: I've ended up with $=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi\alpha n(1- \alpha )}\alpha^{\alpha n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{-n(1-\alpha)}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n(1-\alpha)}(1-\alpha)^{n(1-\alpha)}} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi\alpha n(1- \alpha)} \alpha^{\alpha n} \left({1-\alpha}\right)^{n(1-\alpha)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n} \alpha^{\alpha n+\frac{1}{2}} \left({1-\alpha}\right)^{n(1-\alpha)+\frac{1}{2}}}$. Does this seem about right?

Comment: Seems reasonable. Have you tried computing a few values to see how they match? Also, you can combine the $n^{th}$ powers like this: $(a^a (1-a)^{1-a})^n$, but that's a personal preference.